# How to set position in css

Tags: html, css

```css
.top{
  width:100%;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:red;
}
.bot{
  width:100%;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:black;
}
.content{
  position:relative;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:white;
  left: 0px;
  bottom:0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class='top'>
<div class='content'>
</div>
</div>
<div class='bot'>
</div>
```

content is not laying on the inner bottom of the first div `.top`, why not `position:relative bottom:0px` works , while positioning on absolute it comes in bottom of the screen , so can I lay that div on the bottom of the first div `.top` using position absolute, content width height have to change though.

Comment: Er...what "javascript files" are you speaking of? This is CSS.

Comment: sorry ive forgotten to edit the previous quesn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.top` and set `position: absolute` to `.content`

```css
.top{
  width:100%;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:red;
  position:relative;
}
.bot{
  width:100%;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:black;
}
.content{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:white;
  left: 0px;
  bottom:0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class='top'>
<div class='content'>
</div>
</div>
<div class='bot'>
</div>
```

Comment: ^ This is what you want.  Make your life easier and format your HTML a little bit to make it easier to read for future updates.

Answer (score 1):

bottom 0px not works with position relative , and if you want to do with postion relative i found a solution for you

```css
.top{
  width:100%;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:red;
}
.bot{
  width:100%;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:black;
}
.content{
  position:relative;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:white;
  left: 0px;
 bottom: calc(-100% + 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class='top'>
<div class='content'>
</div>
</div>
<div class='bot'>
</div>
```